# Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 587) action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I get this error when the app send email :

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 587):
  app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:66:in `block in create'
  app/controllers/incidents_controller.rb:62:in `create'


  Rendered /home/jeremymontesinos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.4ms)
  Rendered /home/jeremymontesinos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/jeremymontesinos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/jeremymontesinos/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (16.8ms)
Cannot render console with content type multipart/form-dataAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0x000000033b4ef0 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0x000000033b4bf8 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">, #<Mime::Type:0x000000033ad330 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:url_encoded_form, @string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">]
```

My development.rb :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => "localhost"}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  adress: 'auth.smtp.1and1.fr',
  port: '587',
  user_name: 'foo@bar.fr',
  password: 'password',
  authentication: :plain,
  enable_starttls_auto: true}
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Environment.rb :

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)
ActionMailer::Base.default :content_type => "text/html"

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

My controller(where i send the command for send the email):

```
  def create
    @incident = Incident.new(incident_params)
    @incident.user_id ||= current_user.id
    @incident.incident_state_id_for_user = 1
    @incident.incident_state_id_for_tech = 1


    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident.save
    @response = Response.new(content: "Incident créé par #{current_user.name} #{current_user.surname}", incident_id: @incident.id, sender_id: @incident.user_id)
    @response.save!
        AppMailer.incident_created.deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to @incident, notice: 'Incident crée.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @incident }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @incident.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

App_mailer.rb : 
class AppMailer < ApplicationMailer

```
  default from: "foo@bar.fr"

  def incident_created()

    mail(to: "bar@baz.com", subject: "Succefull !", body: "You're really cool!")

  end

end
```

And application_mailer.rb:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "foo@bar.fr" #Here is a fake mail adress
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

So i use LinuxMint 17.2, Server Puma on rails, rails 4.2.3 ...

EDIT : I tried to ping the server with : telnet auth.smtp.1and1.fr 587 and it works

I tried to change the port to : 25 and 465 and it not working

Comment: It looks like a bad host name (`localhost`) instaead of a port issue...

Comment: `adress`? Should not be `address` ?

Comment: HO MY GOD ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Change in your `development.rb` the `adress` config into `address`.

It's just a typo! ;-)

As you can see from error, the connection tried was on the right port, but on the wrong host, so the issue was to be searched on hostname config (at least, that's the way I found it)